# How to extend XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, extends, xmlstreamreader

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html

I want to extend the XMLStreamReader but it's an interface.

I want to do something like:

```
public class GraphDataStreamReader extends XMLStreamReader{

  public GraphDataStreamReader(){
    super();
  }

  public void nextStartElement() throws XMLStreamException {
    do {
      super.next();   
    } while (!super.isStartElement());
  }
}
```

Other class:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
GraphDataStreamReader streamReader = (GraphDataStreamReader) factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile)); //returns XMLStreamReader
streamReader.next(); //method from XMLStreamReader
streamReader.nextStartElement(); //method from GraphDataStreamReader
```

Is this posible? If yes, then how?

Comment: use "implements" instead of "extends"

Comment: If you have Java 6 or above you can extend [StreamReaderDelegate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html).

Comment: @McDowell: That looks like what i've searched for.
But there is an error at the cast. Could you please make an answert to the question?

Comment: You generally *implement* an interface (with a class).  You can "extend" an interface (but only with another, child interface.  Never a class).  And in your case, you probably want to find (or write) a class that *already implements* XmlStreamReader ... and then extend that class.  Google for "java implements XmlStreamReader", and you'll see that StreamReaderDelegate" is one such class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to extend [StreamReaderDelegate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html):

```
class GraphDataStreamReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {
  public GraphDataStreamReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
    super(reader);
  }

  public void nextStartElement() throws XMLStreamException {
    do {
      super.next();
    } while (!super.isStartElement());
  }
}

XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
GraphDataStreamReader streamReader = new GraphDataStreamReader(
                                 factory.createXMLStreamReader(fileInputStream));
streamReader.next();
streamReader.nextStartElement();
```

Comment: I've tried it like that but the new streamReader is null.

Comment: `streamReader` can never be null in this code - a new object is assigned to it on the declaration line.

Comment: You'r right ;) I had a mistake in the code... 
Thank you, know it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the delegation pattern, like this:

```
public class GraphDataStreamReader implements XMLStreamReader {

    private XMLStreamReader delegate;

    public GraphDataStreamReader (XMLStreamReader delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws XMLStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    ... similar for other methods of XMLStreamReader ...

    ... then add your own methods ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Manfreed, thanks for your help. I don't think this is what i'm looking for. Besides there is already a delegate class (as McDowell wrote) -> StreamReaderDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved it (after alot of attempts).

The extended XMLStreamReader with own methodes:

```
public class GraphDataStreamReader extends XMLStreamReaderImpl {
  public GraphDataStreamReader(InputStream arg0, PropertyManager arg1) throws XMLStreamException {
    super(arg0, arg1);
  }
  public boolean nextStartElement() throws XMLStreamException {
    ....
  }
}
```

Class using GraphDataStreamReader:

```
public class GraphDataParser {
  private GraphDataStreamReader graphSR;

  private GraphDataParser(String xmlFile) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFile));
    graphSR = new GraphDataStreamReader(inStream, new PropertyManager(1));
  }
}
```

Thanks for all your ideas. Most credits to McDowell. Because of his post i keept trying.
I hope this question is still usfull for someone else.

Comment: Is this extending `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl`? That isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yes, why? Works fine.

Comment: This is internal API; if you upgrade your Java runtime or run on a different implementation that class might not be there.

Comment: I didn't know that. How do i see that this is a internal API?

Comment: It is not documented in [the standard Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). You can also use the [jdeps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html) tool with the __jdkinternals__ option. The word _internal_ in the package name is also a clue.